# How to completly disable LLMNR?

Tags: networking, server, systemd, resolvconf

By default, with `LLMNR=yes` set in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, here are the port bindings (using `netstat -l -p -a -n`):

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8214/systemd-resolv
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      8214/systemd-resolv
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*                           8214/systemd-resolv
udp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                                8214/systemd-resolv
```

When `LLMNR=no` is set in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, I still have the following bindings:

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*                           8214/systemd-resolv
udp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                                8214/systemd-resolv
```

How can I completly unbound all LLMNR port bindings?

---

System: Ubuntu server 15.04

Answer (score 10):

After setting LLMNR=no in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
Have you tried restarting the systemd resolved service issuing the command below?

```
systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

Comment: This works as desired.